# Confusion regarding plot of linear convolution vs fast convolution via FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, convolution, fast-convolution

### Question

> [image]
>
> [Example `5.23` of [Digital Signal Processing Using MATLAB Third Edition By Vinay K. Ingle and John G. Proakis](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Digital_Signal_Processing_Using_MATLAB/kZkIAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)  ]

---

I am not getting same plot/results as book although I am using almost same code

The issue with book code is that, I get error for `NI` variable and MATLAB says `NI` is undefined, (I have red-underlined `NI` in Snapshot), so I used `NL` in my code and `NL=N*L`, but I am not getting output as book

---

### My Code

```
clc;clear all;close all; 
conv_time = zeros(1,150); fft_time = zeros(1,150);
%
for L = 1:150
tc = 0; tf=0;
N = 2*L-1; nu = ceil(log10(N*L)/log10(2)); N = 2^nu;
for I=1:100
h = randn(1,L); x = rand(1,L);
t0 = clock; y1 = conv(h,x); t1=etime(clock,t0); tc = tc+t1;
t0 = clock; y2 = ifft(fft(h,N).*fft(x,N)); t2=etime(clock,t0);
tf = tf+t2;
end
%
conv_time(L)=tc/100; fft_time(L)=tf/100;
end
%
n = 1:150; subplot(1,1,1);
plot(n(25:150),conv_time(25:150),n(25:150),fft_time(25:150))
```

---

### My Output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `NI` in the book is just a typo, it should be `N` instead (not `N*L` as in your code). Apart from that, remember that book was written about $25$ years ago, and the code was run on a $33$ MHz $486$ PC. So in order to see some effects on today's computers, you should crank up the value of `L`.

I've modified the code a bit (see below). Now the figure illustrates the expected result.

```
L = 200:500:10000;
K = length(L);
conv_time = zeros(1,K); fft_time = zeros(1,K);
Nav = 10;

for k = 1:K
    tc = 0; tf=0;
    Lk = L(k);
    N = 2*Lk-1; nu = ceil(log10(N)/log10(2)); N = 2^nu;
    for I=1:Nav
        h = randn(1,Lk); x = rand(1,Lk);
        t0 = clock; y1 = conv(h,x); t1=etime(clock,t0); tc = tc+t1;
        t0 = clock; y2 = ifft(fft(h,N).*fft(x,N)); t2=etime(clock,t0);
        tf = tf+t2;
    end
    conv_time(k)=tc/Nav; fft_time(k)=tf/Nav;
end

plot(L,conv_time,L,fft_time)
```

[image]

Comment: your code worked awesome. But why you are dividing tc and tf ,both by Nav?

Comment: @engr: It's averaging. `tc` and `tf` are the times of `Nav` convolutions, so by dividing by `Nav` you compute the average times.

Comment: Tiny minor comment: `log10(N)/log10(2)` could become `log2(N)`

Comment: @LaurentDuval: That's right, I just left that part of the original code unchanged. Maybe matlab didn't have `log2` back then ...

Comment: $N = 2*Lk-1;$                                                                                                 
        $nu = ceil(log10(N)/log10(2));$                                                               
          $N = 2^(nu);$                              
                                                                                                                     
                      What are these parameters/variables, i am unable to found these formulas or their explanation in proakis. If comfortable,please guide

Comment: @engr: $2L-1$ is the minimum required FFT length to avoid circular convolution artefacts. The actual FFT length $N$ is chosen such that it is the smallest power of $2$ that is greater than or equal to $2L-1$. FFTs lengths that are powers of $2$ result in especially efficient implementations.

Comment: Ok,thanks you clarified regarding 2L-1, but please also guide about "nu = ceil(log10(N)/log10(2)); N = 2^nu;"

Comment: @engr: I actually already did. As I said, $N$ is chosen as the power of $2$ that is greater than or equal to $2L-1$. So you compute the logarithm (with base $2$) of $2L-1$, chose the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to that number (`ceil`), and then you take $2$ to the power of that number.